# Objective-C self->_ivar access with explicit vs implicit self->

Tags: objective-c, block, reactive-cocoa, ivar

## General Problem

Until now, I always thought `self->_ivar` is equivalent to `_ivar`. Today I found out that this is not entirely true.

See, for example the following code snippet:

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject {
    NSString *_testIVar;
}
@end

@implementation TestClass

- (instancetype)init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _testIVar = @"Testing Only";
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)test
{
    {
        NSInteger self = 42;
        NSLog(@"without arrow: %@", _testIVar);        /* OK              */
        NSLog(@"with    arrow: %@", self->_testIVar);  /* COMPILER ERROR! */
    }
}

@end
```

Even though I hid the original `self` with some `NSInteger` also named `self`, the implicit ivar syntax `_testIVar` still finds the "original" self whereas `self->_testIVar` obviously does not. In the latter case the compiler correctly complains with

> Member reference type 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') is not a pointer

In the first case however, it just works.

## The Real-world Problem

This example might seem rather artificial but it's not at all. For example the [ExtObjC](https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc/blob/master/extobjc/EXTScope.h) project (used by [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) ) defines the very handy `@weakify(var)` and `@strongify(var)` which help against strongly capturing `self` (and other objects) in blocks by defining a really handy syntax (no need to write the odd and cumbersome to write `__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self; [...] ^{ __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf; [...] }`  anymore). For example:

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    @weakify(self);
    dispatch_async(self.someQueue, ^{
        @strongify(self);
        NSLog(@"self @ %p", self);
    }
}
```

Without `@weakify` and `@strongify`, the block would capture a strong reference to `self`. With the `@weakify` and `@strongify` it doesn't. So the deallocation of `self` would not be postponed until the block has been run. The main advantage though is that you don't need to remember to use `weakSelf` or `strongSelf` instead of `self` because the "original" `self` is hidden.

That's very handy, the ExtObjC implements `@weakify` / `@strongify` by generating something similar like the following with macros:

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    __weak typeof(self) _weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_async(self.someQueue, ^{
        __strong typeof(self) self = _weakSelf;
        NSLog(@"self @ %p", self);
    }
}
```

Fair enough, that's even better because we can just continue to use `self` without actually capturing a strong reference to `self`. However, as soon as we use the implicit-ivars-of-self-syntax, a strong reference to the "original" `self` will still be captured!

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    @weakify(self);
    dispatch_async(self.someQueue, ^{
        @strongify(self);  /* compiler warning: Unused variable self here!!! */
        NSLog(@"self->_testIVar: %@", _testIVar);
    }
}
```

## Misc

When using ivars in blocks, we're definitely capturing `self`. See for example this screenshot:
[image: Unused and captured self].

Another fun thing about the screenshot is that the warning messages are

> Unused variable 'self'

and in the line below

> Capturing 'self' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle

That's why I think there are two versions of `self` :-)

## Question

The actual question here is: What exactly does `_testIVar` mean? How does it find the "original" `self` pointer?

To clarify (also see my screenshot): As @MartinR pointed out (which is what I think as well), there is some special version of `self` which cannot be changed and is only used for implicit-self-ivar-access. Is that documented somewhere? Basically where is defined what the implicit `self` refers to? It seems to behave the same way that for example Java does (with `this`) but with the difference that `this` is a reserved keyword that you cannot override.

The question is also not how to "fix" it, just writing `self->_testIVar` will be what I want in the `@weakify`/`@strongify` example. It's more that I thought by using `@weakify`/`@strongify` you cannot make the mistake of implicitly strongly capturing `self` anymore but that simply does not seem to be the case.

Comment: I'm surprised to learn that `self` isn't a reserved word o_O

Comment: But in every `- (instancetype)init` method you do `if ((self = [super init])) { ... }`, no? So you _assign_ to `self`, therefore it can't be a reserved keyword.

Comment: @Joe, I don't think that is the case because if you write `self->_block = ^{ NSLog(@"%@", _block); };` (assuming that `_block` is an ivar of block type), there will be a compiler warning "Capturing 'self' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle". So it _does_ retain `self` and not only the ivar.

Comment: I meant reserved as in preventing you from declaring variables with that name inside a class method. Irrelevant to your question really just a commentary.

Comment: @BradAllred, ah, I see you point.

Comment: It's interesting that you get a compiler error if you **don't** redefine `self` in a new block (i.e. at the top-level of a method).  However thinking about it, that's no different from any other variable.

Comment: My conjecture is that `_ivar` is equivalent to `self->_ivar` where `self` is the *implicit first argument* that each Objective-C method call has, even if there is a local variable of the same name. I don't have an official reference for that (otherwise I would write an answer :-) , but my first attempts to read the generated assembler code confirm this conjecture.

Comment: @MartinR that's exactly what I think. The screenshot I added makes that pretty clear :-)

Comment: @JohannesWeiß: On the other hand, `self = [super init]` also overwrites self, and in that case it is *expected* that `_ivar = ...` sets the instance variable of the "new self". So this might be a special issue with blocks.

Comment: There is not other self. Objects are structures. if you write self->_testItVar you access data member of structure self, if you write only   _testIVar you access ivar from current structure that is visible. And if you write self->_testIVar, you send message to self to return value of _testIVar. In your example with block, that block is mean as function and _testIVar without self is visible in function. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: @baltov So, the "structure that is visible" is a reference to the original (non-overridden) `self`, isn't it? If yes, that's basically a non-accessible separate `self` variable. But where's that defined?

Comment: the structure that is visible is structure in stack
:) dont forget a stack.

Comment: @MartinR: "So this might be a special issue with blocks." I don't see anything different. It seems consistent to me. Direct instance variable access never uses a `self` variable that you define yourself. It always uses the implicit `self` variable that the compiler defines for the method.

Comment: @newacct: Yes, that comment was written before I investigated the problem further and wrote the answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

All Objective-C methods are called with two hidden arguments (from the ["Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html)):

- The receiving object
- The selector for the method

and a method can refer to the receiving object as `self` (and to its own selector as `_cmd`).

Now `_ivar` is equivalent to `self->_ivar` where `self` is this *implicit first 
function parameter*.
As long as you don't define a new variable `self` in an inner scope, `_ivar == self->_ivar` holds true.

If you define a new variable `self` in an inner scope then you have

- The locally defined `self`,
- the "implicit self" which is the first function parameter,

and `_ivar` still refers to the "implicit self"! This explains the compiler warnings in your block, which seem to contradict each other:

- *"Unused variable 'self'"* refers to the locally defined `self`,
- *"Capturing 'self' strong in this block ..."* refers to the "implicit self" of the function.

The following code demonstrates also this:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    NSString *_ivar;
}
@end

@implementation MyClass

- (void)test
{
    _ivar = @"foo"; // Set instance variable of receiver
    {
        MyClass *self = [MyClass new]; // Redefine self in inner scope
        self->_ivar = @"bar"; // Set instance variable of redefined self
        NSLog(@"%@ - %@", self->_ivar, _ivar);
        // Output: bar - foo
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: "So _ivar (in an instance method) refers to the instance variable of the receiver of the method." Not necessarily true. If you assign to `self` (not create a new variable in an inner scope; but assign to the `self` variable that already exists), then access instance variables, they will access instance variables on the object that `self` now points to, which is not necessarily the same as the receiver of the method.

Comment: @newacct: Yes, you are right. I will try to improve the answer later. Thank you for the correction!

Comment: @newacct: Actually the statement "A method refers to the receiving object as self" from the Apple documentation would then also be wrong if you assign a new value e.g. with `self = [super init]`.

Comment: @newacct: I have rewritten the answer, your feedback is welcome.

Comment: Good to know. I always use explicit `self->` access and this gives me a reason. Thanks :)